# Why each c++ project can only build one executable in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Is this visual studio specific or all c++ projects behave this way?

Why??

Comment: Because the inventers of Visual Studio thought it makes sense?

Comment: That's why solution (`.sln`) files exist: to gather several projects.

Comment: Is this the case with other IDEs?

Comment: No. Some IDEs can have multiple targets within a project. Kdevelop and Eclipse, for example.

Comment: How would you do it in eclipse?

Comment: @wp2: Borland/Embarcadero IDEs work the same way as VS.  A single project (a .bpr file) outputs a single executable, but you can group multiple projects together (a .bpk file).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to build more than one executable, then you can have several projects defined in the same "solution" file.

Comment: This, and also there's nothing to stop you using some or all of the same files within multiple projects in the same solution. e.g. If you want to build both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a component,  without having to perform two separate builds with different configurations, then your solution might have two projects that point at exactly the same files but have different outputs and slightly different setups.

Answer (score 1):

How would you make the difference between the 2 different main of the two program ? It is quite complicated to know which source is for the programe 1 and which source is for the program 2. Thus, you need 2 different projects for 2 executable.

If you have shared source code between your two project, you can have a library (in a different project ^^).

Answer (score 1):

C++ generally has no concept of a solution... the Standard only defines what happens in the context of each translation unit (some of which relates to creating objects that can link properly).  The most widespread project build tool used for development is probably still `make`, which allows multiple targets to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Because in Visual Studio, the term "project" is *defined* to be the entity (a set of source files) that emits **one** binary build artifact (dll / exe / static lib / ...).

Note: A project actually can and does generate different binary artifacts (debug vs. release vs. configuration-xy) but normally all from the same set of source files.

If you want to create more than one executable with a varying but overlapping set of source files, then you should split your solution into multiple projects:

- The overlapping set(s) of source files go into a project(s) generating a static lib(s) (or DLL if you want)
- The unique set of source files for each executable go into a separate project for each executable and each executable project links to the static-lib project(s).